# Deployed my own VPN server using SoftEther. Websites are still blocked; advice needed. Further details inside

Tags: networking, security, vpn, proxy, firewall

So, as the title says, I set up my own VPN using SoftEther. I tested it on a few un-restricted devices, and it seems to work fine. Using it on a managed device, however, still results in blocked websites, just like before. The managed device has a global http proxy. All this is happening on my own network. I need advice on where to go from here.

This is the main thing I found after some exploring:

The web proxy doing the filtering sees my VPN's IP address, while websites/etc see the IP address of the web proxy (for the most part). The one exception I've found to this is when connecting to IRC networks; they still see the VPN's IP address. The VPN is putting almost all traffic through the web proxy, which is why blocked websites are still blocked.

Is there anything I can do to get around this? Or is this the end of the line? I don't really care about the difficulty of a possible solution; I'd just like to know about it.

I also found the web proxy's configuration (if that's what you'd call it?).

```
/* Modify but do not remove the following 3 lines */
/* For Cloud, the swgdomain should be the cloud host (ncxxx-cncxxxx.ibosscloud.com), the swgpublicIP should be your home network NAT IP address, and the domain should be your domain or your custom login page domain */
var swgdomain = "[REDACTED]"


var domain = "[REDACTED]"
var swgpublicip = "[REDACTED]"

/* MOST PEOPLE WILL NOT NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE: */

/* EAM 20170822, don't change the template without consulting [REDACTED] */
function FindProxyForURL(url,host) { 

hostIP = dnsResolve(host)
swgpublicip = dnsResolve(swgdomain)

/*  Bypass the proxy for local resources: */

if (isPlainHostName(host) || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*.local") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "10.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "172.16.0.0", "255.240.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "192.168.0.0", "255.255.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "169.254.0.0", "255.255.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "224.0.0.0", "240.0.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "240.0.0.0", "240.0.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "0.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "127.0.0.0", "255.0.0.0")  
    ) {return "DIRECT"; } 

/* These domains are for your equipment specifically: */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*" + domain) ||
    (host == swgpublicip) ||
    (hostIP == swgpublicip) 
    ) { return "DIRECT"; } 

/* These are for Google SSO: */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*gstatic.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "accounts.google.com")
    ) { return "DIRECT"; } 

/* These are for Apple devices (such as iPads): */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*appleiphonecell.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*thinkdifferent.us") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*airport.us") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*ibook.info") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "captive.apple.com") || 
    shExpMatch(url, "http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*itools.info") || 
    shExpMatch(url, "http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html") ||
    shExpMatch(host, "*guzzoni.apple.com") )
{ return "DIRECT"; } 

/* This section is for Microsoft: */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*download.microsoft.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*ntservicepack.microsoft.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*windowsupdate.microsoft.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*update.microsoft.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*cdm.microsoft.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*wustat.windows.com") || 
    shExpMatch(host, "*windowsupdate.com") ||
    shExpMatch(host, "*windowsupdate.microsoft.com") )
{ return "DIRECT"; }

/* Captive portals (hotels and such) and local preferences: */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*wayport.net") )
{ return "DIRECT"; } 

/* This is for iboss servers */

else if (shExpMatch(host, "*.iboss.com") ||
    shExpMatch(host, "*.ibosscloud.com") ||
    isInNet(hostIP, "208.70.72.0", "255.255.248.0") || 
    isInNet(hostIP, "206.125.41.128", "255.255.255.192") )
{ return "DIRECT"; }

/* The final proxy statement: */

else if (dnsResolve("myiboss.net") == "208.70.74.18") 
    { return "PROXY " + swgpublicip + ":8009"; } 

/* If on network, go direct (no proxy): */

else { return "DIRECT"; }
}
```

Comment: All you have done is make is so while your connected to the vpn you use proxy.  Stop using your proxy.

Comment: Right. The thing is that I can't remove the proxy from the device. How do I get around it? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Why exactly can’t you disconnect from the proxy?

Comment: It's a managed device (an iPad, in this case). It's been configured to connect through a certain http proxy. I can't disconnect from the proxy without disconnecting from the internet. Unless you mean blocking the proxy somehow on my VPN server?

Comment: Can you modify the proxy config file or only view it?

Comment: View-only, unfortunately. The trouble seems to be that the device is connecting to the VPN first, and the http proxy second. Is there any way to reverse the order of that?

Comment: @JohnLHoward If you are not in a position to chnage the configuration then you won’t be able to.  If you were in a position to chnage it you would have already changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the device will try to connect to the proxy if it believes it is not on its own LAN, I see two options :

- intercept the connection to the proxy on your router, diverting it to your own proxy / a public proxy (how to do this will depend on your router, not always possible)
- fool the device into believing it is on its LAN. Looking at the config file, we see that it tries :

  ```
  else if (dnsResolve("myiboss.net") == "208.70.74.18")
  { return "PROXY " + swgpublicip + ":8009"; }
  ```

  so configuring your DNS server to return something OTHER than 208.70.74.18 for myiboss.net should do the trick (this may require changing DNS server, should be possible on most routers).